# How do I calculate a monster's unarmed attack, specifically for slam?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, homebrew, damage

I'm making a custom monster, a huge flesh golem. I'm trying to determine its unarmed strike as a much larger monster for slam, and need to calculate its damage to determine its offensive challenge rating so I can calculate its actual challenge rating.

So far I know that the medium sized Flesh Golem has these stats for slam:

> ***Slam.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +7 hit, reach 5ft., one target. *Hit:* 13 (2d8+4) bludgeoning damage. (MM p.169)

I get that hit dice use constitution to calculate hit points, but when I tried to apply the same equation with strength to determine damage I was off, which makes me believe there is a formula I just don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how we can get the (existing) Flesh Golem's stats:

#### +7 to hit:

+3 proficiency, +4 STR. You know the flesh golem's proficiency bonus is +3 because it's a CR5 monster; you look this up on the table "Proficiency Bonus by Challenge Rating" on MM p.8.

#### 2d8+4 bludgeoning damage:

+4 STR, the 2d8 is the golem's natural "weapon", its fists. That die type/number is not tabulated anywhere--it's one dial you can tweak for damage when trying to create your monster's offense.

---

You can find much *excellent* advice on creating custom monsters in [Angry GM's Monster Building 101/201/202 articles](http://theangrygm.com/?s=monster+building). Be warned that his writing, while full of good advice and wisdom, is liberally sprinkled with rude and vulgar language.

You may have noticed that CR -> proficiency bonus -> damage -> offensive CR -> ... CR? Yes, there is a feedback loop in there. Angry GM's walkthroughs on creating monsters do a very good job of explaining things like this, pointing us to where the actual dials are that one can tweak.

Comment: Wait that can't be right. Don't you use dexterity to make a hit?

Comment: To hit: in the world of weapons it's STR for most melee, choice of STR/DEX for "Finesse" keyworded weapons, DEX for most ranged, "Thrown" ranged attacks take the stat they'd have used when not thrown. In the case of the Flesh Golem I can see that the +7 comes partly from +3 proficiency (CR5), leaving +4 to account for. The golem's STR is +4 (vs. a DEX of -1), so that must be the stat that the designer is using to describe its melee attack. Which makes "flavor" sense for a "Slam" attack.